# ob_get_clean() remove value of input

Tags: javascript, php, forms

console.log(ab_id_transakce); return empty variable because there is in php ob_get_clean(). Im novice so i dont understand what this doing. If i remove line with ob_get_clean() ab_id_transakce have correct variable from form input.

How to make function affilate() works also with ob_get_clean()?

```
<?php
            ob_start();
                ?>
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail *" class="required">
                      <button type="submit" class="full-width secondary submit-form" onclick="affilate()"><span class="outer-no-height align-center"><span class="middle"><i class="ct-icon-envelope"></i></span><span class="middle">Send</span></span></button>
                    </form></div>

                    <script>
function affilate() {                   
    var ab_instance = "xxxx";
    var ab_kampan = 3;
    var ab_cena = 1; 
    var ab_id_transakce = document.getElementById("email").value;          
                                
console.log(ab_id_transakce);
    
            var script_tag = document.createElement("script");
        script_tag.src = "https://xxxx.cz/t3.js";
        script_tag.type = "text/javascript";
        script_tag.async = true;
        script_tag.defer = true;
        document.head.appendChild(script_tag);  
}
</script>
                </div>  
            
                <?php
          $html_form = ob_get_clean();
            ?>
            <div class="something">
```

Comment: What does `ob_get_clean()` do? Include that code here as well.

Comment: @user1599011 it's a built-in PHP function, so the OP won't have code for it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

Comment: koupmi why do you want/need to use ob_get_clean? If it works without it, then what's the problem to simply remove it, as you've already done? Does that cause you a different problem?

Comment: I found ob_get_clean() only in this one line. Im not sure what it do, but it break html if i comment it out

Comment: Well that's because presumably you're using `$html_form` later on in the code (which you haven't shared here) to output something. P.S. If you don't know what the function does, did you think of looking in the PHP documentation? If you didn't before, I've just posted a link to that in my earlier comment.

Comment: Why, overall, are you using output buffering though? There are use cases for it, but it's not clear whether your situation really requires it.

Comment: There is calculator next to form, so its related with this. Its not mine code, i just need add script to form. But it doesnt work for ob_get_clean function what probably not include mine script or not return back value from input.

Comment: Are you sure the buffering is really the cause here? Or is it just a coincidence? It doesn't make a lot of sense to be honest. Your JavaScript code cannot run until the user clicks the button to trigger the function. That happens within the finished page in the browser, after it has been output by PHP. That happens long after PHP's server-side output buffering has finished working, or had any influence over anything.

Comment: Have you inspected the finished source code of the page to ensure that your script tag is included in the right place in the page? Have you ensured there are no errors in the Console when you try to click the button? Have you used the JavaScript debugger to step through the code and check whether the affiliate() function is actually being executed successfully? It's hard to see how the buffering could be related but if you can look in a bit more detail about what the browser is actually working with, it might give some sort of extra clue about what's going on.

Comment: I dont have any errors in console, my script works when is commented ob_get_clean().  In source code i can see onclick also my javascript. With ob_get_clean() script return variable with empty value (instead input id.value) .

Comment: The buffering shouldn't have any effect on that - all it does is delay the outputting of all the content to later in the lifetime of the PHP script. But the PHP script will still have finished by the time the page is sent to the browser, and the user has typed in the box and clicked the button. I can only assume there is some other contributing factor which you haven't shown to us. Please ensure your question contains a [mre] of the issue you're reporting.